# getting python and react component based container to work

Tags: python, reactjs, docker, react-dom, docker-container

I am attempting to dockerize this workflow of [isomorphic app](https://medium.com/@__amol__/going-isomorphic-with-python-and-react-f4664183f0c4).
I build the container of below docker file.

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
        apt-get -y install vim && \
        apt-get -y install nano && \
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /statics/js

VOLUME ["/statics/"]

WORKDIR /statics/js

COPY requirements.txt /opt/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /opt/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "/statics/js/app.py"]
```

and this was the result:

```
$ docker build -t ciasto/pythonreact:v2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.327 MB
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.5-slim
 ---> b27a94c44674
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs &&     apt-get -y install vim &&   apt-get -y install nano &&      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c76cb348707c
Step 3/9 : RUN mkdir -p /statics/js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2ef5b24f551c
Step 4/9 : VOLUME /statics/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e62c6af1867
Step 5/9 : WORKDIR /statics/js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5a018e8c727
Step 6/9 : COPY requirements.txt /opt/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1fa4dccc6608
Step 7/9 : RUN pip install -r /opt/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 8845a0efcee7
Collecting TurboGears2==2.3.10 (from -r /opt/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading TurboGears2-2.3.10.tar.gz (176kB)
Collecting Kajiki==0.6.3 (from -r /opt/requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading Kajiki-0.6.3.tar.gz (174kB)
Collecting tgext.webassets==0.0.2 (from -r /opt/requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading tgext.webassets-0.0.2.tar.gz
Collecting dukpy==0.1.0 (from -r /opt/requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading dukpy-0.1.0.tar.gz (2.0MB)
Collecting WebOb>=1.2 (from TurboGears2==2.3.10->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading WebOb-1.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
Collecting crank<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 (from TurboGears2==2.3.10->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading crank-0.8.1.tar.gz
Collecting repoze.lru (from TurboGears2==2.3.10->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading repoze.lru-0.6.tar.gz
Collecting MarkupSafe (from TurboGears2==2.3.10->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting nine (from Kajiki==0.6.3->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading nine-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webassets (from tgext.webassets==0.0.2->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading webassets-0.12.1.tar.gz (179kB)
Collecting cssmin (from tgext.webassets==0.0.2->-r /opt/requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading cssmin-0.2.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: TurboGears2, Kajiki, tgext.webassets, dukpy, crank, repoze.lru, MarkupSafe, webassets, cssmin
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for TurboGears2: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for TurboGears2: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/51/1d/bb/c9cfdcf2a49f71955d5b66aed0dbd187e58e5d77a9fa34a4af
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Kajiki: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Kajiki: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/ad/fe/15/33e02c73fead4ea9238fcd31d273accf6fb9d922ec901e20c8
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tgext.webassets: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tgext.webassets: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/00/f2/09/0378f24bd9151b7a927093546c11685899ebec451b65eb181f
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dukpy: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dukpy: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/21/29/46/34c303b9dca370a8ccc97a84b094c8089b78edde125b0a1fcb
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for crank: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for crank: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/1c/00/54/4dcfd62d8268d7b34ea607bd9f8cb12aa930a7718c8c5fbc02
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for repoze.lru: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for repoze.lru: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b2/cd/b3/7e24400bff83325a01d492940eff6e9579f553f33348323d79
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/88/a7/30/e39a54a87bcbe25308fa3ca64e8ddc75d9b3e5afa21ee32d57
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for webassets: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for webassets: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/9d/cb/c2/340b9b695822b6954840bcb6cd147b3a7cfc2bcd922296e63e
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cssmin: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cssmin: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c3/79/88/647f59be446af4e9867362ca6e961cc7f218bd793fbdc351a6
Successfully built TurboGears2 Kajiki tgext.webassets dukpy crank repoze.lru MarkupSafe webassets cssmin
Installing collected packages: WebOb, crank, repoze.lru, MarkupSafe, TurboGears2, nine, Kajiki, webassets, cssmin, tgext.webassets, dukpy
Successfully installed Kajiki-0.6.3 MarkupSafe-1.0 TurboGears2-2.3.10 WebOb-1.7.2 crank-0.8.1 cssmin-0.2.0 dukpy-0.1.0 nine-1.0.0 repoze.lru-0.6 tgext.webassets-0.0.2 webassets-0.12.1
 ---> 86c189792ae7
Removing intermediate container 8845a0efcee7
Step 8/9 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in 9243a87c36e2
 ---> e7d35d54e66d
Removing intermediate container 9243a87c36e2
Step 9/9 : CMD python /statics/js/app.py
 ---> Running in 6e3b53cd901d
 ---> 0d79c4f81f3b
Removing intermediate container 6e3b53cd901d
Successfully built 0d79c4f81f3b
```

So my first question is what does the step 9 means ? does that mean it is attempting to run the `/statics/js/app.py` path even before I run the container because that would not work as I planned to mount this `statics` volume from the `host`. 
Secondly, if I run the command:

```
$ docker run -it -v ~/Development/my-Docker-builds/pythonReact/statics/:/statics/ -d  ciasto/pythonreact:v2
```

`03d77c87651e752450e3be0aa64a0841c088b32a1db5424ad96c150c949d0366`

I get the hash key but nothing works ! I do not even see the start trace or error message of `app.py` had any error.

So how should I run the `app.py` from host mounted volume when I run the container ?

Comment: It's doing what you told it to: `CMD ["python", "/statics/js/app.py"]`

Comment: but when i try to open page at `localhost:8080` i dont get anything

Comment: When you don't specify the external port one gets chosen randomly. Add `-p 8080` to your run command.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `CMD` as the startup script for the container. Having said that at step 9 it is only marking `pyhton /statics/js/app.py` to be executed whenever you start the container. Also, since you are using `-d` flag you won't be able to see logs so you have to fetch them using `docker logs` command as:

```
docker logs 03d77c87651e752450e3be0aa64a0841c088b32a1db5424ad96c150c949d0366
```

The logs should be enough to help you figure out the issue. I hope it helps.